# embedded jetty cannot be connected

Tags: java, jetty, server

embedded jetty in the application with follow codes,but cannot requested success.
it waited for ever.

```
public static class TestHandler extends ContextHandler {
    public TestHandler(String contextPath) {
        super(contextPath);
    }

    @Override
    public void doHandle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.doHandle(target, baseRequest, request, response);
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Server server = new Server(new QueuedThreadPool(5, 4));
    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
    connector.setPort(9001);
    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { connector });

    HandlerCollection handler = new HandlerCollection();
    ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    contexts.setHandlers(new Handler[] { new TestHandler("/test") });

    handler.setHandlers(new Handler[] { contexts, new DefaultHandler() });
    server.setHandler(handler);
    server.start();
    server.dumpStdErr();
    server.join();
}
```

but changed the Server contstructor to other one,it will be ok, can somebody explain the reason?
 I trace the code,can not find the reason.thanks !!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(9001);

    // Server server = new Server(new QueuedThreadPool(5, 4));
    // ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
    // connector.setPort(9001);
    // server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { connector });

    HandlerCollection handler = new HandlerCollection();
    ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    contexts.setHandlers(new Handler[] { new TestHandler("/test") });

    handler.setHandlers(new Handler[] { contexts, new DefaultHandler() });
    server.setHandler(handler);
    server.start();
    server.dumpStdErr();
    server.join();
}
```

ps: with jetty-server  9.1.0.M0 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have at least a max of 6 in the thread pool:

> "Insufficient threads: max=5 < needed(acceptors=1 + selectors=4 +
>   request=1)"

Change the constructor to this:

```
Server server = new Server(new QueuedThreadPool(60, 6));
```

**Update:**

My logback.xml (src/main/resources)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="false" scanPeriod="10 seconds">

<appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <Target>System.out</Target>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%p %d{HH:mm:ss} [%c{1}] - %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="DEBUG" />

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
</root>
```

**StackTrace:**

```
...
INFO 11:25:18 [o.e.j.s.Server] - jetty-9.3.0.M0
WARN 11:25:18 [o.e.j.u.c.AbstractLifeCycle] - FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@9f10da5d: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Insufficient threads: max=5 < needed(acceptors=1 + selectors=4 + request=1)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Insufficient threads: max=5 < needed(acceptors=1 + selectors=4 + request=1)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:351) ~[jetty-server-9.3.0.M0.jar:9.3.0.M0]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.3.0.M0.jar:9.3.0.M0]
at TestHandler.main(TestHandler.java:43) [classes/:na]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Insufficient threads: max=5 < needed(acceptors=1 + selectors=4 + request=1)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:351)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at TestHandler.main(TestHandler.java:43)
```

Comment: I change log level to DEBUG,did't find the message,which java file dose this message exist? thanks

Comment: I used Slf4J + Logback as the logging framework. I think some messages of your app are not getting logged, see [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-logging.html#selecting-log-framework).

Comment: I also used slf4j+logback

Comment: can you paste you logback.xml content,I changed level to TRACE,also find the warning message

Comment: A thread count that low is only really good for unit testing single requests.  It will hurt normal production performance significantly.  For production consider a much more meaningful value.